# How to stop OS from asking to execute markdown files?

Tags: cinnamon, manjaro, nemo

I am on Manjaro with Cinnamon as DE, so I use Nemo as my file manager. Whenever I double-click markdown (`.md`) files, I get a dialog asking if I want to execute the file or edit in a text editor. The default editor associated with `.md` is `Typora`.

I understand that this is partly because the execute flag is set on the file; if I remove the execute permission the file opens in `Typora` like I expect with no dialog prompt. However, this is not practical as a solution:

- Seems like Nemo creates files with execute set by default, so disabling it every time is tedious.
- I notice that some file systems don't seem to allow unsetting the execute flag, such as encrypted volumes.
- I may want to keep a file executable *and* have the default behavior be opening it in an editor.

Surely somewhere there must be a setting to the tune of "Default behavior for executable files: Display/Run/Ask". Where is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually more like Run/View/Ask. :)

Go to *Edit > Preferences > Behavior tab*. In the **Executable Text Files** section, you should find the options you're looking for. It's a global setting, so it can't be applied to just a single file type. Also, setting to view by default apparently prevents executing the files from within Nemo.